# Use AngularJS filter of a column with filter option

Tags: angularjs

i have a table with ng-repeat where it has a colunm with filter as follows:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="objin listOfObj |filter: searchObj">

    {{ (listAllElmt | filter:{idElt: obj.id})[0].nameElt || ''}}    
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

the search part is done with the following instruction:

```
<label >Elmt label</label> 
<input type="text"   ng-model="searchObj.id">
```

Here the user must write in the  input the id in order that filter:searchObj return a result, however, it must write the name which is a logic way and not putting the id.

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used another variable where i created it in html as follows:

```
<label >Elmt label</label> 
<input type="text"   ng-model="searchObj.id">
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="obj in listOfObj |filter: searchObj">
{{objInterm = obj;
objInterm.id = (listAllElmt | filter:{idElt: obj.id})[0].nameElt || '';

 ;''}}
    {{ objInterm.id}}    
  </tr>
</tbody>
```